# letting the user know props of component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, visual-studio-code, components

i would like to know if there is a way to show the user what props a component can get without using typescript.
an example from material UI:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this [addon](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OfHumanBondage.react-proptypes-intellisense) for Visual Studio Code. It allows you to use the proptypes without TypeScript.